# Как показать число заказов каждого покупателя из определенной страны?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Доброго вечера!
у меня есть 2 таблицы `Orders` и `Customers`.
В первой - `Orders` есть столбец `CustomerID` (который совпадает с CustomerID в таблице `Customers`)
Во второй - `Customers`таблице есть столбец `Contactname` и `Country` .
Навидите пожалуйста на мысль как можно посчитать количество покупок для каждого покупателя?

на всякий случай прилагаю схему БД [схема бд](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ad43beb5737bc55c90d3b6dd120fcfe1316238ea/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f493236773954392e706e67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже поздно, что-то голова не варит:

```
SELECT Customers.Contactname, 
       Customers.Country, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) AS CustomerOrders
       FROM Customers
       WHERE CustomerOrders > 1
       ORDER BY CustomerOrders DESC
```

Comment: единственное что добавил так это where country ='france'
спасибо!

Comment: малюсенький вопрос к Вам, сейчас счет идет с 0, а как сделать чтобы выводились те у кого > 1?

Comment: Обновил для вас

Comment: так я пробовал, говорит недопустимое имя столбца

Comment: `select
t1.ContactName,
t1.Country,
count(*)
from Customers t1
inner join Orders t2 on t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
group by t1.ContactName, t1.Country
having count(*) > 1`

это как вариант, но как сделать чтобы в Вашем варианте работало
where customerorders > 1 and country ='france'

Comment: Согласен, писал ночью вчера и забыл что при группировке нужно использовать HAVING.

Answer (score 3):

```
select c.ContactName, c.Country, count(o.Id) from Customers c
left join Orders o on c.Id=o.CustomerId
where c.Country='France'
group by c.Id, c.ContactName, c.Country
having count(o.Id)>=1
```

Если нужно отфильтровать по наличию определенного количества заказов - добавляем `having count(o.Id)>=N`, где N - минимальное количество заказов.

[Фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e83e45/5)